# Codacy "Found fs.functionName with non literal argument at index 0" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, codacy

Error messages and my codes:

Found fs.existsSync with non literal argument at index 0

```js
if (!fs.existsSync(dbFolder)){
```

Found fs.mkdirSync with non literal argument at index 0

```js
fs.mkdirSync(dbFolder);
```

Found fs.readFileSync with non literal argument at index 0

```js
const content = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${this.dbFolder}/${this.dbName}.json`, "utf8"));
```

Found fs.writeFileSync with non literal argument at index 0

```js
fs.writeFileSync(`${dbFolder}/${dbName}.json`, "{}");
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 3):

if you wonder what's the problem, it's in the error message. It's bad practice to use a non literal (a variable) on  fs.readFileSync first argument.

See https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security#detect-non-literal-fs-filename

Comment: The link to owasp was not working in the link. So please provide some more info if you know how we can solve this issue.

Comment: it is working for me: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal. anyway the answer says the problem: you are using variables instead of string literals. the problem is that the variable can be changed (is it user input?) and allow path traversal atacks

Comment: does eslint giving false positive? Lets say if i pass path.join parameter to fs readFile or writeFile it is giving error. But i cannot use relative url, so any alternative?